# How to create color transition programmatically

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I want to make color transition for a background page, for example from blue-lightblue-white- and many more. I tried using `.gif` file, but it did not work on the phone. I think maybe it can be done using changing the value of `RGB` or `ARGB` programmatically, but I don't know how to make it. Can anyone tell me how? Thanks before

Comment: Do you really need to make a picture? You can assign a gradient to the `Background` property of any control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by using a storiboard. For example:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Name="Storyboard1" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot">
            <DiscreteColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Blue"/>
            <DiscreteColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="LightBlue"/>
            <DiscreteColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="White"/>
            <DiscreteColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3" Value="White"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

When the page is loaded, you start the Storyboard:

```
this.Storyboard1.Begin();
```

Comment: It does work. Just start storyboard when the page is loaded: `this.Storyboard1.Begin();`

Comment: Good work @anderZubi!  Thanks for completing the post with the full working solution.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to write the `this.Storyboard1.Begin();` . Thanks!